# what is return null? and why is it used in this component?

Tags: reactjs

Hello I need help to understand, about return null
I just see some tutorial in youtube about React
and code is like this

This component is used to make the page goes to the top everytime the pathname is changed, but what I dont understand is that the reason of the use of 'return null' here because even if I remove the return null, the code works perfectly and it doesnt cause any issue

Is it good to use return null here, or actually it does not matter? And also is there any reason to use return null in React?

```
...
const ScrollToTop = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);
  return null;
};

export default ScrollToTop;
```

I already tried to delete the "return null" and test the website and it's still work, So I wonder what is the use of return null here